# Can iOS devices send PUT requests to Rails apps?

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ios, nsurlconnection, put

We've tried numerous times sending update PUT requests to our Rails server and we keep receiving a 404 "The page you were looking for does not exist"

Our update method is very simple (practically generic rails).

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

When I run CURL from the command line to test the update method, it works fine. But, when I try the same methods in objective-c, it always results in a 404 error.

So my question is: can iOS devices send PUT requests to servers using NSURLConnection or is this not implemented?

UPDATE::

**This doesn't update the database**

```
NSString *dataString = @"user[first_name]=bob";
NSData *postBodyData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [dataString UTF8String] length:[dataString length]];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"example.com/users/1.json"];
NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:fullURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"PUT"];
[request setHTTPBody:postBodyData];
self.todoConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
```

**This updates the database**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"example.com/users/1.json?user[first_name]=bob"];
NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:fullURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"PUT"];
self.todoConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
```

Comment: Posting Ruby code when your question is about iOS support probably won't do you any good. If you instead post your Objective-C code, we can look and see if you are setting the HTTP method correctly (as David V illustrated below).

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I'm writing the rails end, and a different developer was writing the objective-c and I didn't have access to his code. It's up now.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that you aren't escaping the '[' and ']' characters. Try setting the HTTP body with data derived from the string @"user%5Bfirst_name%5D=brian".

Comment: I wasted almost a day figuring this out.

Comment: This sounds like a security hole.  How would you authenticate the PUT request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make an NSMutableURLRequest and set the HTTP method:

```
- (void)setHTTPMethod:(NSString *)method
```

Give it the string `@"PUT"`.

Here is how you can create an NSURLConnection from such a request.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *myMutableRequest[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
[myMutableRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myMutableRequest delegate:myDelegate];
```

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. POST and GET requests do work.

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your URL, parameters, or headers. Did you debug the request to verify that it is correctly formatted? You could try just putting in the exact string your provided to cURL in your request and see if that helps.

Comment: Hm, this is interesting. When I tried to add body data to the PUT request via [request setHTTPBody:@"user[first_name]=brian"] it would respond with a 200 response, but it wouldn't update the database record. HOWEVER, when i append the data to the URL, it changes. For example: test.com/users/1.json?user[first_name]=joe <-- via PUT, and it works!

Answer (score 7):

Actually @akshay1188 has a workable solution, but I think the more elegant approach is to add the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type to the request:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the HTTP method type as @"POST"

And add a parameter to the request body as:
@"PUT" for key @"_method"

It should work.

Comment: could you be so polite and provide full working example?