# iOS : end point for PUT method

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlrequest

I have a server that I can connect to it, insert data with POST method with this end point :

```
PUT /Movies
```

I want to update serve  and implement PUT method I have an end point

```
PUT /licenses/:id
```

but I do not know how to implement PUT, Would you please help me in this implementation, I do not know how to write this --> part /:id

for my POST I had

```
    NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"movies"];
    .
    .
    .
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

and it works great I can Insert new staff to server and json file, but How can I implement PUT?
I had research and found that they are similar to each other, my problem right now is how to write my end point

```
 PUT /Movies/:id

 NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"?????"];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
```

I appreciated if you can help me!

Comment: You just have to set the HTTP Method as PUT. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10938584/366346

Comment: @GoodSp33d what about endPoint

Comment: Are you actually using RestKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) putMovie:(NSString*)movieId {

  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Movies/%@", movieId];
  NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:path];
  /** Add necessary parameters */
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

}
```

EDIT: 
I Agree with Nikita Took, you should use AFNetworking if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use `AFNetworking` as library for passing data over network. Here is example with AFNetworking:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSString *putPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@", userId];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"param":@"value"};
[client putPath:putPath parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

Here is link to repository with examples and code: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)